# Git under Cygwin prompts for ssh-askpass

Tags: git, cygwin, openssh

`ssh-askpass` is normally an alias for the GUI-style program that prompts you for password, it normally comes with X or display manger... Cygwin provides no such thing / I don't want to install X for this...

What happens / why am I getting this prompt? Why can't it just read it from terminal?

**EDIT:**

This is what `git config --list` prints for me:

```
git config --list
core.symlinks=false
core.autocrlf=false
color.diff=auto
color.status=auto
color.branch=auto
color.interactive=true
pack.packsizelimit=2g
help.format=html
http.sslcainfo=/bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt
sendemail.smtpserver=/bin/msmtp.exe
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
rebase.autosquash=true
```

Comment: What's the output of `git config --list` in your repository?

Comment: @wxvw I'm not sure I understand.  Are you saying you haven't cloned a repository yet?  In that case, just `git config --list` from anywhere would be elucidating enough.

Answer (score 0):

After much struggle and search, finally I found this: https://superuser.com/questions/158673/cygwin-git-bizarre-terminal-issue 
A poor combination of bad defaults, inconsistent API and package maintainers overrun with the daily routine...